# I installing react nodejs on my computer and tried running npx create-react-app .\ on my powershell console and got this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, powershell

npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cach

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ohiosumua Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

Comment: please provide the full error. also try to format your question better